# Manipulating strings in python list

Tags: python

I have a list of tweets that is grouped into chunks of tweets within the list like so:

```
[[tweet1, tweet2, tweet3],[tweet4,tweet5,tweet6],[tweet7, tweet8, tweet9]]
```

I want to count the number of occurences of each word within each subgroup. To do this, I need to split each tweet into individual words. I want to use something similar to str.split(' '), but I receive an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Is there a way to split each tweet into its individual words? The result should looks something like:

```
[['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word2', 'word2'],['word1', 'word1', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5'],['word1', 'word3', 'word3', 'word5', 'word6']]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a list of strings

```
tweets = ['a tweet', 'another tweet']
```

Then you can split each element using a list comprehension

```
split_tweets = [tweet.split(' ')
                for tweet in tweets]
```

Since it's a list of lists of tweets:

```
tweet_groups = [['tweet 1', 'tweet 1b'], ['tweet 2', 'tweet 2b']]
tweet_group_words = [[word
                      for tweet in group
                      for word in tweet.split(' ')]
                     for group in tweet_groups]
```

Which will give a list of lists of words.

If you want to count *distinct* words,

```
words = [set(word 
             for tweet in group
             for word in tweet.split(' '))
         for group in tweet_groups]
```

Comment: This gives the OP an extra level of unwanted list nesting

Comment: @sshashank124 This wasn't clear to me when I first read it. see edit

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
l1 = [['a b', 'c d', 'e f'], ['a b', 'c d', 'e f'], ['a b', 'c d', 'e f']]

l2 = []
for i,j in enumerate(l1):
    l2.append([])
    for k in j:
        l2[i].extend(k.split())

print(l2)
```

[DEMO](http://repl.it/kE9)

Answer (score 1):

```
groups = [["foo bar", "bar baz"], ["foo foo"]]
[sum((tweet.split(' ') for tweet in group), []) for group in groups]
# => [['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz'], ['foo', 'foo']]
```

EDIT: It seems an explanation is needed.

- For each group `[... for group in groups]`

  - For each tweet, split into words `(tweet.split(' ') for tweet in group)`
  - Concatenate the split tweets `sum(..., [])`

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? This is the most elegant and Pythonic solution by far.

Comment: @Shashank: I actually like tobyodavies's solution quite a bit, now that he started answering the right question :) So I wouldn't say mine is the most elegant, but thank you.

Comment: Yes, his solution with the nested for-loop comprehension is great as well, I upvoted it. However, I still like this one the most and don't believe it deserves a downvote with no reason.

Comment: This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted. ... Yeah, I got nothin'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the occurrences then use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict, chaining all the words with [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) after splitting.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

tweets  = [['foo bar', 'foo foobar'], ['bar foo', 'bar']]
print([Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split,sub)))  for sub in tweets] )
[Counter({'foo': 2, 'foobar': 1, 'bar': 1}), Counter({'bar': 2, 'foo': 1})]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that you pass your list to that will assemble and return a dictionary of the words and how many times they show up in your tweets.

```
def countWords(listitem):
    a = []
    for x in listitem:
        for y in x:
            for z in y.split(' '):
                a.append(z)
    b = {}
    for word in a:
        if word not in b:
            b[word] = 1
        else:
            b[word] += 1
    return b
```

this way you will keep both your list and be able to assign the return value back to a new variable for inspection.

```
dictvar = countWords(listoftweets)
```

creating a definition will allow you to place this inside of its own file that you can always import use in the future.